# Am I passing parameters correctly?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the function `getFilename` to prompt the user for which file to read and then pass that to the function `readFile` which calculates the numbers in the file and then (using `displayAverage`) display the average of the numbers in the file.

I'm new to coding and can't figure out why it doesn't seem to be using the `readFile` function... the program prompts the user for the file but after that it just inputs a blank line. Am I calling the functions & passing the parameters correctly?

```
void getFilename(char fileName[])
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   return;
}
```

```
float readFile(char fileName[])
{
   cout.setf(ios::fixed);
   cout.precision(0);

   ifstream fin(fileName);
   int sum = 0;
   int numValue = 0;
   float grades = 0;
   float average= 0;

   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error opening file \"" << fileName << "\"";
      return false;
   }

   while (!fin.eof())
   {
      fin >> grades;
      sum += grades;
      numValue++;
      if (numValue != 10)
         cout << "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"";
   }

   fin.close();
   average = sum / 10;

   return average;

}
```

```
void displayAverage(int average)
{
   cout << average;
   return;
}
```

```
int main()
{
   char* fileName;
   int average;

   getFilename(fileName);
   readFile(fileName);
   displayAverage(average);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour since `fileName` does not point to anything valid that can hold data.

Unless you are required to use an array of `char`s to hold the filename, use `std::string` for `fileName`.

```
std::string fileName;
```

If you are required to use an array of `char`s to hold the filename, use

```
char fileName[FILENAME_LENGTH];
```

Make sure `FILENAME_LENGTH` is large enough for your needs.